# get_context_data method doesn't work in django

Tags: python, django, web

I have a class based view that inherits from CreateView and I have some fields that I want to be sent in the page through context dictionary and the get_context_data doesn't work because non of the context fields doesn't appear in the page.

the class:

```
class IncomeCreateListView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'users/incomes_&_spendings.html'
    form_class = IncomeCreateForm

    def get_context_date(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(self, **kwargs)
        incomes = Incomes.objects.filter(
            user=self.request.user, created_date__year=datetime.now().year, created_date__month=datetime.now().month)
        if datetime.now().month == 1:
            incomes_last_month = Incomes.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user, created_date__year=datetime.now().year - 1, created_date__month=datetime.now().month + 11)
        else:
            incomes_last_month = Incomes.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user, created_date__year=datetime.now().year, created_date__month=datetime.now().month - 1)
        total_incomes = round(assembly(incomes), 2)
        total_incomes_last_month = round(
            assembly(incomes_last_month), 2)
        context['title'] = 'Incomes'
        context['object_name'] = 'Incomes'
        context['primary_color'] = 'primary'
        context['objects'] = incomes
        context['total_sum'] = total_incomes
        context['total_sum_last_month'] = total_incomes_last_month
        context['year'] = datetime.now().year,
        context['month'] = datetime.now().month,
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `get_context_datE`, while its `get_context_datA`

Comment: Jesus, thanx :D

Comment: np, have a good one and please accept the answer if its not hard :)

Comment: Sorry I was gone in a trip and I didn't hat time, now I accepted it